# Does the Medialink Wireless-N AP support transparent LAN bridging?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router

I would like to set up my new [Medialink Wireless-N Router](http://www.medialinkproducts.com/wirelessRouter.php) as a "transparent bridge" to my LAN such that wireless clients appear to be on the same network as the wired.

Does this AP support such a configuration, and if so how do I enable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it always bridges between its LAN ports and wireless. So turn its DHCP server off and plug one of its LAN ports into your existing Ethernet LAN (e.g. one of the LAN ports of your upstream router), and it'll do what you need.

I RTFM'd for you and the User Manual tells you how to do this step by step under the heading "Router to router configuration".